# PHP PDO Insert into database function issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So I'm creating a basic cms application to try and learn PDO a bit more in depth, but I seem to have stumbled upon an issue. I want to be able to use a function to insert data into a MySQL database, and so far I've got this code...

```
    public function insert($table, $rows, $values) {

        $data = $values;

        $STH = $this->DBH->("INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (". $rows . ") values (?, ?, ?)");

    }
```

Do the question marks for the values represent the number of pieces of data I will be entering into the database? If so how can I know the amount of pieces of data that are going to be entered based upon the $data array? (All $values will be entered with the format 'value, value2, value3' and so on)

Hopefully I've made myself clear on what I'm asking, I'm pretty bad at explaining myself haha.. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need to know what you are inserting...it's not magical.

Comment: What @DanyCaissy said.  Also, the things you call `$rows` in your codesample are not rows but columns or fields, maybe that this is the origin of your confusion?

Comment: it'd be helpful to see what's in $rows, but unless that comes out to be something like `foo,bar,baz` you're probably generating invalid SQL. your field count has to match the values count (e.g. if $rows is 4 fields, then specifying 3 placeholders for the values is a syntax error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a prepared statement with a random number of values, as long as your values are an array. Example (untested):

```
public function insert($table, $rows, $values) {
  $params = rtrim(", ", str_repeat("?, ", count($values)));
  try {
    $stmt = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($rows) VALUES ($params)");
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($values); $i++) {
      $stmt->bindValue($i, $values[$i-1]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Oops... {$e->getMessage()}";
  }
}
```

**Edit** Passing only two parameters (`$table` and `$data` as an associative array), you could do something like this (untested):

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
  $keys = array_keys($data);
  $values = array_values($data);
  $params = rtrim(", ", str_repeat("?, ", count($values)));
  try {
    $stmt = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (`".implode("`,`", $keys)."`) VALUES ($params)");
    $stmt->execute($values);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Oops... {$e->getMessage()}";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your $data variable is an array, you can just pass it to the execute method in the PDO::Statement after it's been prepared. When question marks are used for binding it just requires a non-associative array of values in the order that you want them bound (in the order your question marks appear in the query)

```
public function insert($table, $rows, $values) {
    $data = $values;
    $STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (". $rows . ") values (?, ?, ?)");
    $STH->execute($data);
}
```

You can also use names for binding:

```
public function insert($table, $rows, $values) {
    $data = array(":col1" => $values[0], ":col2" => $values[1], ":col3" => $values[2]);
    $STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (". $rows . ") values (:col1, :col2, :col3)");
    $STH->execute($data);
}
```